# Stopping and firing an event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, jquery-events, confirm

I'm click on a 'a' tag and the page is redirecting at some domain. Now I have written some function on the 'a' tag click which uses `e.preventDefault()`. I'm keeping target safe in another variable using `var temp = e.target;`.

But when I'm trying to fire it again it is not firing up without any js error.

Here is the code :-

```
   var allowedReload = false;
   var reloadTargetControl = null;

   $('a').click(function (e) {
   debugger;
   if (allowedReload == undefined || allowedReload == false) {

    reloadTargetControl = e.target;

    e.preventDefault();

    pageLeaveConfirmBox(); /*this function is creating custom confirm box with Yes/No button*/


    /******* Custom confirm box - yes button code *******/

    $("#popUpBtnYes").click(function () {
        debugger;
        allowedReload = true;
        $(reloadTargetControl).click(); /*this step is executing the same script again but nothing is happening, can any one explain it why? */
    });
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to trigger an event manually you should use trigger function:

```
$(reloadTargetControl).trigger('click');
```

Other than this you could improve your code by changing:

```
if (allowedReload == undefined || allowedReload == false)
```

to

```
if (allowedReload === undefined || !allowedReload)
```

Comment: Sorry code didn't work :(

I have changed few lines :-

 var reloadTargetHref = e.target.href;

 window.location = reloadTargetHref; /*this works instead of $(reloadTargetControl).trigger('click'); */

Comment: @GaganDeepSharma: best way to allow us helping you to fix it is to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your #popUpBtnYes click function you set `allowedReload` to true, but where is the `else` portion of your conditional that would handle that true condition? You've sent a click event to the original target but not supplied any expression to handle the changed state. I think all you need is `else { return true; }` in order for this to work.

Comment: Try using `console.log(reloadTargetControl);` to get the current value of reloadTargetControl in the `else`. In my tests, it goes from being the anchor node to being just the URL. Not quite sure why that happens, but it seems you could work with it (window.location=....)
http://jsfiddle.net/V2Lyx/

Comment: works with window.location = e.target.href;

But i also need to fire same code for the submit button, in that case window.location would't work.